# time difference betweern varchar field and timestamp field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two dates fields as below (I know they are incorrectly design but DBA will not changed it)

```
   order_tag varchar(2)    dt_changed timestamp(6)
   06:35:13                27-MAR-17 06.10.31.036561
```

And I know to find the time difference between the `timestamp_field` and the `varchar(2)` field.

I tried the below sql and get an ora error:

> ORA-01850: hour must be between 0 and 23

```
select orq.order_tag,
       rt.dt_changed, 
       (to_date(rt.dt_changed,'hh24:mi:ss') -
         (to_date (orq.order_tag, 'hh24:mi:ss'))) time_differ
from   order_request orq,route rt
where  orq.rt_id = rt.rt_id
```

ORA-01850: hour must be between 0 and 23

Comment: Don't store date/time data in varchar columns, use proper data types!

Comment: Is ORDER_TAG really VARCHAR(2)?  How were you able to fit a string of length 8 in a column that allows only two characters at most?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TO_DATE( date_string, format_mask )` takes a string as the first value and you are passing in a `DATE` datatype. To solve this, Oracle will implicitly call `TO_CHAR( date_value, format_mask )` on the date to convert it to a string and will use your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format mask.

If you do:

```
SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

You will see the format mask that Oracle is using and it almost certainly does not match the `HH24:MI:SS` mask you are using in `TO_DATE`.

Instead, you can try explicitly calling `TO_CHAR` and specifying the format mask:

```
select orq.order_tag,
       rt.dt_changed, 
       to_date( TO_CHAR( rt.dt_changed, 'HH24:MI:SS' ),'hh24:mi:ss') -
         to_date (orq.order_tag, 'hh24:mi:ss') time_differ
from   order_request orq,route rt
where  orq.rt_id = rt.rt_id
```

Comment: the query works but the time differ does not seems to be correct                                                                                     ORDER_TAG DT_CHANGED TIME_DIFFER
06:00:13 27-MAR-17 06.10.31.036561 0.007152778
06:00:14 27-MAR-17 06.15.31.031092 0.010613426
06:05:13 27-MAR-17 06.29.50.911644 0.017094907
06:10:13 27-MAR-17 06.24.53.850697 0.010185185
06:11:13 27-MAR-17 06.13.40.959042 0.001701389
06:12:14 27-MAR-17 06.15.13.467060 0.002071759
06:13:13 27-MAR-17 06.13.14.199357 1.15741E-05
06:15:13 27-MAR-17 06.31.46.591367 0.011493056

Comment: I do it with one record
ORDER_TAG DT_CHANGED     TIME_DIFFER
06:00:13 27-MAR-17 06.10.31.036561 0.007152778

Comment: @sbirdi Can you explain what the aim of that comment was as your point is unclear.

Comment: ok (just show 1 row as an example from the output
the order_tag =06:00:13 and dt_changed = 27-MAR-17 06.10.31.036561 so i would suspect the time differ to be around 10 mins 31 secs

Comment: but is is showing with the above query as 0.00715277777777778

Comment: @sbirdi 0.007152 days ~= 10.3 minutes

Comment: ok, makes sense, how can I get it to display results as hh:mm:ss, please

Comment: @sbirdi Multiply by 24 (and truncate) to get hours; multiply by 24*60 and truncate (mod 60) to get minutes; and multiply by 24*60*60 (mod 60) to get seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the result in `INTERVAL` data type, not `NUMBER`. If you convert both values to `DATE`, the difference is a `NUMBER` (in days) which then you need to convert to your desired format. By the way, to convert your timestamp to date, you shouldn't use TO_CHAR; it is much simpler than that, just use `CAST( your_timestamp AS DATE )`.

But you don't need that. Instead, just convert your VARCHAR2 to TIMESTAMP, using `TO_TIMESTAMP( ..., format_model)`. The difference of two timestamps is an INTERVAL, exactly what you want.

**Setup** (note - your first column is surely not varchar(2)!)

```
create table test_data (order_tag varchar2(20), dt_changed timestamp(6));

Table TEST_DATA created.

insert into test_data 
  values ('06:35:13', to_timestamp('27-MAR-17 06.10.31.036561', 'dd-MON-rr hh24.mi.ss.ff'));

1 row inserted.
```

**Query** (note the number of days - your `ORDER_TAG` column doesn't have a date, so by default it's the first day of the current month. If that's no good for your business, then you should also store the date, not just the time of day.)

```
select to_timestamp(order_tag, 'hh24:mi:ss') - dt_changed as time_diff from test_data;

TIME_DIFF
-------------------
-25 23:35:18.036561
```

If you must "attach" the date from DT_CHANGED to the string in ORDER_TAG, you can do silly things like this (not recommended):

```
select to_timestamp(to_char(dt_changed, 'dd-MON-rr') || order_tag, 'dd-MON-yyhh24:mi:ss')
        - dt_changed as time_diff from test_data;

TIME_DIFF
-------------------
+00 00:24:41.963439
```